# How to apply function to each 2d matrix in an array

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have a function that takes an X*X matrix as input, and returns a vector of length X.

I would like to apply that function to an X*X*Y array, and get back an X*Y matrix/array of the results from the function.

I can apply the function to one matrix with

```
funcName(arrayName[,,1])
```

but I can't figure out how to apply the function to each of the matrices. I'm sure it's simple - using apply or sapply or lapply, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just before posting my question, I tried one more thing.

[The reference material for apply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) tells you that the MARGIN argument should be set to 1 for rows, and 2 for columns. I tried both of those without success, but then thought to try setting the MARGIN argument to 3 - that did the trick, and gave me the exact output I wanted.

To be exact, I did:

```
apply(arrayName, MARGIN=3, FUN=funcName)
```

Comment: This works because the MARGIN parameter is actually just a vector of the margins you want to collapse over in your array. Most common arrays just have two dimensions (for rows and columns) but if you have higher dimension arrays, you can specify those as well. You can also combine over multiple dimensions at once: `MARGIN=c(1,3)` or something like that.